# Error in $a.getCallback() [sforce is not defined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I've found a way to open a VF rendered as PDF inside lightning using:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject(contentDocumentId);
```

But then, when I try to open same file at classic salesforce the following error appears:

> "Error in $a.getCallback() [sforce is not defined]."

So, I found a way to open the PDF at classic salesforce:

```
window.location.href = 'http://salesforce.com/LINKPDF';
```

The problem is the *window.location.href* solution open the PDF and quit app. I need a way to keep the app opened and show the PDF just like the *navigateToSObject* solution.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in Classic, you can open a new window (`window.open(...)`), or you could use an iframe, etc. There's no standard solution in Classic, which is the point of the newer frameworks (Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience).